# How to create a 3d shape with a bend

Tags: css, 3d, css-shapes, bezier

I want to be able to create a 3d shape similar to a cymbal. [Here](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/PwWjLL) is a link to the bend I want. But I want it to have a `x` & `y` axis.

Here is the basic css that I have started with:

```
div{
  width:300px; height:300px;  
  border:solid 5px #000;
  border-color:#000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/300px 300px 0 0;
  background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

With the code above. It only creates a curved border. I need to change to become a shape itself.

An example of the solution would be to extract the black area of the following example, click "eye" : [here](http://paulrhayes.com/experiments/sphere/)

[image: Example]

How can I create this by using pure CSS? I have looked into bezier curves & external JS functions that could maybe facilitate this.

Anyone seen/have a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Paulie_D Give me a chance :P Updated! Thanks for the comments

Comment: Use an SVG would be my answer but it's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to create a 3d object using CSS. Think of drum cymbal or the outer layer of a sphere. But it would still have an x, y & z axis.

Comment: Is it a symbal? I though it was an eye.

Comment: If you remove the white space. It practically is a cymbal. @GolezTrol

Answer (score 4):

You can't really create a proper 3D shape in css or svg since they operate on a 2D plain.

But you can create lots of 2d plains to make it look 3D:

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
.wrapper {
  perspective: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper .cymbal {
  top: 175px;
  left: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.wrapper:hover .cymbal {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
}
.wrapper .cymbal div {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper .cymbal div:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .cymbal div:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  transform: translateZ(15px) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .cymbal div:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translateZ(10px) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .cymbal div:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translateZ(5px) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .cymbal div:nth-of-type(5) {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  transform: translateZ(0px) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .cymbal div:nth-of-type(6) {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  transform: translateZ(-5px) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .cymbal div:nth-of-type(7) {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transform: translateZ(-10px) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cymbal">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is turning out to be the best fit. Using 2d shapes to make the overall 3d object using layers in this case `<div>`'s. I'll have a go at implementing this! Thanks for answering!

Comment: One could even argue that all "3d" shapes in computer graphics are composed of "flat" triangles... ;)

Comment: @m01 you are correct sir.

Answer (score 2):

### CSS transform

Creating a [cymbal shape](http://www.rhythmtraders.com/images/products/10809.jpg) is possible with a CSS transform, more specifically the `perspective` transform.

To make it any more 3d will require multiple elements or using browser specific properties to get a close effect.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(50deg);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #000000 1%, #fceabb 2%, #fccd4d 30%, #f8b500 31%, #fbdf93 100%);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This looks like the solution. Will test it out by manipulating the perspective. But thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: But looking at the code. It looks like it does not facilitate the bend that was the initial problem.

Comment: You cannot "bend" in CSS. CSS has 3d transforms but it does not have the power to create 3d style elements.